# docker images fail to start because of unknownhost exception while trying to communicate with external host

Tags: docker

I have a spring boot service which runs fine as spring boot app. I have created docker image out of it using docker file. When the image start, application seems starting fine till a point when it try to resolve external host (I have couple fo external service configured based on profile and I am running in dev profile which will communicate with external service like consule , mysql etc). It throws unknownhost exception. Same application run fine and able to run and communicate with external services while running it as spring boot app/service in my local machine . It seems like the issue is between host and docker container not able to use dns of host. Any help, how can I resolve the issue ?

Comment: Is your external ip is in the same subnet as docker subnet? What is your external ip address?

Answer (score 0):

From the Docker documentation:

> https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname
>
> **DNS services**
>
> By default, a container inherits the DNS settings of the Docker
>   daemon, including the /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf.You can override
>   these settings on a per-container basis.
>
> ```
> Flag         Description
> --dns        The IP address of a DNS server. To specify multiple DNS servers, use 
>              multiple --dns flags. If the container cannot reach any of the IP
>              addresses you specify, Google’s public DNS server 8.8.8.8 is added, 
>              so that your container can resolve internet domains.
> --dns-search A DNS search domain to search non-fully-qualified hostnames. 
>              To specify multiple DNS search prefixes, use multiple --dns-search flags.
> --dns-opt    A key-value pair representing a DNS option and its value. See your
>              operating system’s documentation for resolv.conf for valid options.
> --hostname   The hostname a container uses for itself. Defaults to the container’s 
>              ID if not specified.
> ```

See also:

- [Docker docs: Configure container DNS](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/)
- [java.net.UnknownHostException on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537977/java-net-unknownhostexception-on-docker)