# com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: when connecting to mongodb docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-java

I have an sbt project which has `mongodb` code i am making a custom image of this sbt project and using `mongodb:2.6.11` public docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

here is the docker file of my sbt project

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8 as stripecommon

MAINTAINER sara <sarawaheed3191@gmail.com>

WORKDIR /myproject

ADD myprojectcode .

CMD ["sbt","reload","clean","compile","run"]
```

and here is the `dockerfile` of the mongodb image mongodb:2.6.11 https://github.com/ky13R/mongo-2.6.11-docker-image/blob/master/Dockerfile

here is how i am running my containers

```
docker create network mynetwork
```

to start mongodb container

```
docker run -p 27017 --network mynetwork mongo:2.6.11
```

to start my project container

```
docker run --network mynetwork myproject:v1
```

and my project is unable to connect to the mongodb server here is the exception log

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

i have followed this tutorial to connect to mongodb server 
https://dzone.com/articles/using-docker-to-shove-an-existing-application-into
what i am doing wrong here?

the code for connecting to mongo server is

```
private val DATABASE:String   = config.getString("db.dbname")
  private val SERVER:ServerAddress = {
      val hostName=config.getString("db.hostname")
      val port=config.getString("db.port").toInt
    new ServerAddress(hostName,port)
      } 
  val connectionMongo = MongoClient(SERVER)
  log.debug("mongo connection created "+connectionMongo)
  def collectionMongo(name:String) = connectionMongo(DATABASE)(name)
  log.debug("getting collection from mongodb")
}
```

and here is the config file

```
db.url="mongodb://Localhost:27017"
db.hostname="Localhost"
db.dbname=testdb
db.port=27017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that you are using `localhost` for `db.url` and `db.hostname`. Localhost referred to the Docker Container of **your** application is inside the container, not your host machine. What you can do is starting the MongoDB container with a concrete name, like this:

```
docker run -p 27017 --name mongodb --network mynetwork mongo:2.6.11
```

And use the following config within your application:

```
db.url="mongodb://mongodb:27017"
db.hostname="mongodb"
db.dbname=testdb
db.port=27017
```

Within your docker network (`mynetwork`), the database container is reachable by it's container name (here `mongodb`)

Hope I can help.

**Edit:**

Another (easier) way to solve this is to "link" the containers. By doing so, you don't need to create a network beforehand.

*How to do it?*

Start your mongo database:

```
docker run -p 27017 --name mongodb mongo:2.6.11
```

Start your application and link to the mongo-db container, previously created:

```
docker run --link mongodb myproject:v1
```

Comment: i am getting the same exception

Comment: 0:08:47.533 12894 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5cde882e46e0fb0062fea051', description='null'}-mongodb:27017] cluster INFO - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb: Name or service not known

Comment: hm, that is something I can't answer. If I start for example a ubuntu container `docker run --link mongodb --rm -it ubuntu:latest bash` and execute `netcat -v mongodb 27017` (after installing with apt) I get a connection: `mongodb [172.17.0.2] 27017 (?) open`. There must be some difference on how `netcat` and `java` resolve hostnames within containers.

Comment: so should i instal mongodb in a custom image rather than using its public image from docker hub?

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from the mongodb image. Java uses different way to resolve the hostname than standard linux tools do. Maybe you can add the solution here in your Dockerfile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32550032/8745384